# PHP split class names from string

Tags: php, regex, string, variables

Hi I have a variable (`$variable1`) that contains the following string:

```
$variable1 = class="our-products type-our-products status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry product-status-previous-product"
```

I want to grab just the last class part of the string (this class name changes to 1 of 3 options):

1. product-status-previous-product
2. product-status-current-product
3. product-status-future-product

What is the best and most efficient PHP command to retrieve the last class name in the list? I was then going to use a switch statement to act depending on the last class name.

Comment: Just explode with a space and get the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your syntax is invalid, I'm assuming you save the entire variable as a string, like this:

```
$variable1 = 'class="our-products type-our-products status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry product-status-previous-product"';
```

You could write a simple function to get all the classes as an array from that pattern, using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and then simply return the last one with the [end](http://php.net/end) method:

```
function getLastClass($variable) {
    // Run a regular expression match on the variable to see if it looks OK
    preg_match('/class="([^"]+)"/', $variable, $matches);
    if (count($matches) === 2) {
        // Things look good, get the classes inside
        $classes = explode(' ', $matches[1]);
        // And return the last one
        return end($classes);
    } else {
        // The string doesn't look like a class definition
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf('Invalid string passed: "%s"', $variable)
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function on your variable to get the last class:

```
try {
    echo "The last class is: " . getLastClass($variable1);
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // Something went wrong...
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: this is perfect, I didn't need to use it all. I changed the format of my variable to an array and used the end method and it worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable1 = "class=our-products type-our-products status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry product-status-previous-product";

$pattern = '/(\w+\-\w+\-\w+\-\w+)\s*$/';
preg_match($pattern, $variable1, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text as opposed to adding plain code. Plain code can be hard to understand and is likely to attract downvotes when posted as such.